# Ajustar Columnas de 2 tablas HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, html-tabla

Actual mente tengo 1 tabla(html) con 2 tablas(html) dentro cuyo problema es que al visualisarse en una pantalla chica se desajustan los encabezados con la tabla 
Mi tabla (ejemplo) :

```
<table width="100%" >

 <tr>
   <table width="100%" >
     <tr>
<th width='25%'>nombre0</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre1</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre2</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre3</th>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <table width="100%" >
  <tr>
<td width='25%'>0</td>
<td width='25%'>1</td>
<td width='25%'>2</td>
<td width='25%'>3</td>
   </tr>
     </table> 
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

En este caso al verse en una pantalla mas chica el 1, 2, terminan bajo nombre0
me gustaria que en este caso sin dejar de usar ambas tablas dentro de la tabla principal poder hacer que no se desajusten los encabezados y estos sigan a las columan

Comment: Cuál es la idea de construir tablas anidadas? Entendiendo mejor lo que quieres realizar te podemos orientar =)

Comment: bueno es un caso donde la tablaA contiene tabla1 y tabla2 la intencion de la tabla 1 es mostrar los encavesados fijos al tope todo el tiempo , mientras que la tabla2 muestra mediante PHP y SQL la lista de registros , la tabla2 tiene el scroll para bajar y ver usuarios varios (esto tiene campos editable)  pero lo unico que hace falta es ajustar ambas tablas para que pueda relacionarse el titulo con la columna

Comment: Pero para lo que quieres realizar no necesitas crear tantas tablas.. sólo especificarle los encabezados en el `thead`, llenas cada columna en `tbody` y puedes fijar dichos encabezados con `css`... te dejo un link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168521/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Al código que compartes le hace falta las etiquetas **TD** a la primera columna.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
            <td  width="50%">
            <table width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <th width='25%'>nombre0</th>
                        <th width='25%'>nombre1</th>
                        <th width='25%'>nombre2</th>
                        <th width='25%'>nombre3</th>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  width="50%">
                <table width="100%" >
                    <tr>
                        <td width='25%'>0</td>
                        <td width='25%'>1</td>
                        <td width='25%'>2</td>
                        <td width='25%'>3</td>
                </tr>
                </table> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola gracias, ya lo cheque y hacia falta pero el resultado es el mismo :( se siguien amontonando los campos de el encabezado y las columnas (me falto comentar que mi tabla original tiene 327 columnas )

Comment: Hola **claus** puedes subir una imajen de tu tabla para ayudarte mejor :)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la propiedad min-width para que cada th y td tengan como mínimo una anchura por lo que impedirías que se vean de forma desordenada, aquí tienes tu ejemplo poniéndole un min-width de 70px, también le he añadido un borde para que se vea mejor el ejemplo:

```css
td, th {
  min-width:70px;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<table width="100%" >

 <tr>
   <table width="100%" >
     <tr>
<th width='25%'>nombre0</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre1</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre2</th>
<th width='25%'>nombre3</th>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <td>
     <table width="100%" >
  <tr>
<td width='25%'>0</td>
<td width='25%'>1</td>
<td width='25%'>2</td>
<td width='25%'>3</td>
   </tr>
     </table> 
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: hola , gracias. una duda las etiquetas correctas del min-width son <script></script> ? creo que lo estoy haciendo mal

Comment: <script> es para añadir funcionalidades con js principalmente, min-width se usa en css, y en tu caso como se ve en el ejemplo que he puesto lo usas en las etiquetas th y td para solucionar tu problema. Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: si ya hice las pruebas muchas gracias , ya esta solucionado :)

Answer (score 1):

El problemas es que no lo estas poniendo en una columna a la tabla 2, debes ponerlo dentro de la etiqueta `<td>` al igual que la tabla 3. espero te ayude

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
     <table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="red" >
       <tr>
        <th width='25%'>nombre0</th>
        <th width='25%'>nombre1</th>
        <th width='25%'>nombre2</th>
        <th width='25%'>nombre3</th>
       </tr>
     </table>
   <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="yellow">
      <tr>
        <td width='25%'>0</td>
        <td width='25%'>1</td>
        <td width='25%'>2</td>
        <td width='25%'>3</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola, ya lo cheque y es verdad me hacia falta el td, lo cual ya aregle pero sigue agrupando mal los encabezados cuando disminulle el tamaño de la pagina :(

Comment: **Claus** una pregunta, si quieres que los encabezados esten alineados con las columnas de la tablas siguientes por que no hacer solo una tabla?

Comment: a es que parte de los requerimientos son que los encabezados sean fijos pero que se pueda desplazar la tabla es decir si veo al usuario 346 pueda seguir referenciando que sus campos pertenecen al nombre numero de empleado y numero de ruta ect (yo habria preferido un filtro pero... que puedo decir)

Comment: Ok, puedes subir una imagen de tu tabla para ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto un codigo de ejemplo... me indicas si es lo que necesitas

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr,
td,
th {
  display: block;
}

tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

thead th {
  height: 30px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
  /* fallback */
}

tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columns 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato 1</td>
        <td>Dato 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato 3</td>
        <td>Dato 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato 5</td>
        <td>Dato 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dato 7</td>
        <td>Dato 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: lo estoy probando se ve muy bien, me estoy tardando un poco ya que my tabla real tiene 327 columnas y cada ejemplo anterior y este me tarda un poco (uff...)

Comment: como estas implementando todo eso? javascript? angular?

Comment: la intencion es que sea una aplicacion hybrida pero se esta implementando en laravel(el frame que se a estado usando) y en otro frame al mismo tiempo codeiginter ...la verdad es que ya estoy exausto X_x

Comment: Porque mostrar 327 columnas en un table no es para nada optimo... de hecho no sé que tipo de información necesitas para tener que mostrar tal cantidad... se me había ocurrido que podrías mostrar una cantidad mas acotada, por ejemplo 10 columnas y el resto dejarla en una exportacion a excel o mostrandola en un modal (esto ultimo tampoco me convence mucho si son tantas columnas)

Comment: peor aun, cada fila cuenta con campos para editar valores (almenos 5 columnas) lo que es una imprudencia ya que todos se actualizan con un boton al mismo tiempo es decir que al hacer el update genera 327 x 5 updates al mismo tiempo en la mayoria de los casos para solo editar 1 o 10 cuanto maximo (si asumimos que mas de 1 usuario hara esto al mismo tiempo....) son cosas que e sugerido ...yo lo llamo desarrollo ético donde uno adicional a la pregunta "puede hacerse" se pregunta "si debería hacerse" esto arrastra una cantidad enorme de malas ideas la verdad

Comment: la poca flexibilidad de la direcion , mas las malas deciciones a dejado la herramienta echa  una suma de complegidades poco utiles pero la vedad es algo que estan pagando y yo pienso dejar T_T creo que me e salido de tema

Answer (score 1):

de antemano agradesco mucho el apoyo a quienes comentaron y propusieron respuestas, fue de gran ayuda
al final logre el proposito de que el encabezado y las filas esten ajustadas para que se pueda ver a cual pertenence a cual cuando la tabla inferior use el scroll para ver mas registros 
este ejemplo tiene 13 campos y los nombres dentro de la fila son de distinto grosor para comprobar el resultado, disculpen si es algo extenso :

```
    <table >
      <tr>
        <td>
         <table >
          <tr>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato uno uno</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos dos</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos tres</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos cuatro</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos cinco</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos dseis</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos siete</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos ocho</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos nueve</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos diez</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos once</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos doce</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato dos trece</td>
          </tr>
         </table>
       <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
         <table >
          <tr>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 1</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 2</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 3</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 4</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 5</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 6</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 7</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 8</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 9</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 10</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 11</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 12</td>
            <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 13</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <t

d style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 1</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 2</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 3</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 4</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 5</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 6</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 7</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 8</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 9</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 10</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 11</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;"> 12</td>
        <td style="min-width:120px" style="white-space:nowrap;">Dato 13</td>
      </tr>      
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

espero que esto le ayude a alguien en el futuro

Comment: Colega, insisto en que es innecesario crear tantas tablas para realizar lo que quieres.. planteate mejorar la estructura!

Comment: la verdad yo estoy aun mas encontrar de esto más aun porque la tabla original tiene campos para editar información y ..bueno una serie de malas prácticas, este es de esos casos de *desarrollo ETICO* donde dejamos de preguntar "si podemos" y "nos preguntamos si deberíamos" , este caso en especial fue impuesto a regañadientes por mi jefe adjunto en este mensaje que si alguien trabaja sobre la misma idea sugiera mejores soluciones (a mi me enoja mucho trabajar así)